# How to insert Adsense Code every After 3 Div Class Element using plain Javascript

Tags: javascript, adsense

I hope someone could help me to fix this problem:

1. Fix my current code and replace banner image sample with google adsense code
2. I'm trying to insert google adsense in every after 3 div class posts

Here's my code link:

https://jsfiddle.net/uea1b7L9/

Ad places appear every after 3 div class:

```html
<div class="media well listing-item listing-item__jobs">
Post 1
</div>
<div class="media well listing-item listing-item__jobs">
Post 2
</div>
<div class="media well listing-item listing-item__jobs">
Post 3
</div>
<!-- Google Adsense Here -->
<div class="media well listing-item listing-item__jobs">
Post 4
</div>
<div class="media well listing-item listing-item__jobs">
Post 5
</div>
<div class="media well listing-item listing-item__jobs">
Post 6
</div>
<!-- Google Adsense Here -->
<div class="media well listing-item listing-item__jobs">
Post 7
</div>

and so on...

<script>
function myFunction1() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("media well listing-item listing-item__jobs"),
    mod = 3;
  for(var i=0; i<x.length; i=(i+mod)) {
   if(i == 0) { continue; }
    console.log(i);
      x[i].insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', "<img src='https://img-aws.ehowcdn.com/340x221p/photos.demandstudios.com/getty/article/81/3/87467116.jpg'>");
  }
}
window.onload=myFunction1
</script>
```

Comment: I have not used Adsense in years, however it appears that all you would need to do is replace the picture with your Adsense code. If memory serves me correctly they give you a code snippet to use and then you can select it to have it rotate. Giving you tell them what adds to rotate. This would insure that they don't repeat. Just keep in mind people hate ads, you start showing a bunch of adds they will leave the site. A few is fine, to many is a deterrent.

Comment: thanks for the comment, my problem is how can i incorporate adsense using my own code above?